# Memory Management in Objective C with C Pointers

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

If I have a pointer to some Data that an Objective C object manages with ARC, does that pointer have any influence on memory being released automatically?

```
const char* fileBytes = (const char*)[receivedData bytes];

// release ownership
recievedData = NULL;
```

would this cause a memory leak in a loop where recievedData (NSMutableData) was allocated with Data each time?

Comment: Try running it under Instruments.

Comment: try  (Product->Analyze). xcode is smart enough to tell you if code (logic) has a memory leak.

Comment: The pointer has no influence on the memory management of ARC. Don't access the memory that `fileBytes` point to any more after `receivedData` is released.